# Comfile pi will not run python script from browser

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am using a Comfilepi to run a php page that calls a python script on click of anywhere on the screen. The php page is called CarWash.php and on click calls executepython.php which then runs pulse.py. Below is the code for executepython.php

```
exec("sudo python pulse.py");
header("refresh:0;url=Wait.php"); 
?>
```

And this is the code for pulse.py

```
import time 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(.05)
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
```

The python script will run from the shell command but will not work from the browser. I am sure the coding is right because on my regular raspberry pi 3B + the python script will run from the browser when called from executepython.php. I have checked the read write executable on the Comfilepi and the file gives rwx access to all. If anyone could help me out that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: If you do `cd /path/to/index.html` in Terminal and then `sudo python pulse.py` does it work?

Comment: Do you have a link to ComfilePi by the way please?

Comment: http://comfiletech.com/linux-panel-pc/comfilepi-start-pack-7-industrial-raspberry-pi-touch-panel-pc-more/